# Presto extract string from array of JSON elements

Tags: sql, arrays, json, database, presto

I am on Presto 0.273 and I have a complex JSON data from which I am trying to extract only specific values.

First, I ran `SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(library_data, '.$books')` which gets me all the books from a certain library. The problem is this returns an array of JSON objects that look like this:

```
[{
  "book_name":"abc", 
  "book_size":"453",
  "requestor":"27657899462"
  "comments":"this is a comment"
}, {
  "book_name":"def", 
  "book_size":"354",
  "requestor":"67657496274"
  "comments":"this is a comment"
}, ...
]
```

I would like the code to return just a list of the JSON objects, not an array. My intention is to later be able to loop through the JSON objects to find ones from a specific requester. Currently, when I loop through the given arrays using python, I get a range of errors around this data being a Series, hence trying to extract it properly rather.

I tried this `SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.domains'), '$[0]')` but this doesn't work because the index position of the object needed is not known.

I also tried `SELECT array_join(array[books],  ', ')` but getting "Error casting array element to VARCHAR " error.

Can anyone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast to `array(json)`:

```sql
SELECT CAST(JSON_EXTRACT(library_data, '.$books') as array(json))
```

Or you can use it in `unnest` to flatten it to rows:

```sql
SELECT *, 
    js_obj -- will contain single json object
FROM table
CROSS JOIN UNNEST CAST(JSON_EXTRACT(library_data, '.$books') as array(json)) as t(js_obj)
```